# Rails console vs MySQL console - Counting rows in a huge table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I'd like to show a graph on how many records a table has, for the last 30 days. I'm going to do a rake task that I will run each day from a cron job.

I just made a test, and I found a weird "issue".
I ran this code in the Rails console:

```
SeenEpisode.count
#=> (57135.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `seen_episodes`
```

I then tested this in the MySQL console:

```
use my_database;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seen_episodes;
1 row in set (3.94 sec)
```

This table has 21 million records.

I ran both tests on my production server, to get real performance numbers.

Other tables with around 500k records, take 80-300ms in the Rails console.

Why does counting (using the same query) the 21m big table in Rails take so much longer than in the MySQL console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess you're on INNODB, where count(*) is not cached.

Comment: Thanks, it was InnoDB, but why was is so much faster in the MySQL console? It was the same query on the same table.

Comment: You said you were testing on two different databases, the second of which is "much bigger".  Since it has to count the rows, a much bigger table would result in a much bigger execution time.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but both tests were on the same database and table.

Comment: OK.  Quick guess - maybe the result was in your query cache?

Comment: Well, possibly :) I guess I'll have to live with it. It's running in the background anyway.